# Can outer parameter pack be expanded with inner parameter pack to be deduced?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

Given overloaded functions `f1`:

```
void f1(int);
int f1(char);
```

And a class template `X` with member template `f`:

```
template<class T>
struct X
{
    template<class U>
    static void f(T(*p)(U));
};
```

The compiler is able to resolve `f1` from part of the function type:

```
X<int>::f(f1); // T = int (specified), U = char (deduced)
X<void>::f(f1); // T = void (specified), U = int (deduced)
```

However, a variadic class template `Y` with parameter pack at both sides:

```
template<class... T>
struct Y
{
    template<class... U>
    static void f(T(*...p)(U));
};
```

Fail to do the same thing:

```
Y<int>::f(f1); // error
Y<void>::f(f1); // error
Y<int, void>::f(f1, f1); // error
```

Note that it's OK if the parameter pack is only at one side:

```
template<class... T>
struct Z1
{
    template<class U>
    static void f(T(*...p)(U));
};

template<class T>
struct Z2
{
    template<class... U>
    static void f(T(*...p)(U));
};

Z1<int>::f(f1); // ok
Z2<void>::f(f1); // ok
```

This showns a problem: the outer parameter pack `T` cannot be expanded while the inner parameter pack `U` is still dependant.
I imagine the compiler could expand `Y::f` to something like below when `Y<int, void>` is instantiated:

```
template<class... U>
void f(int(*p0)(U0), void(*p1)(U1));
```

where `U0` and `U1` denote the first 2 elements of parameter pack `U`.

But it seems that compilers(g++/clang) refuse to do so and leave the whole `p` unexpended.
where in the standard does it specify such a behavior? Could it be a standard defect or something to improve?

Comment: I think that the problem is in substituting the explicitly specified argument of the outer pack.. Since at that time, the inner pack is still empty, so you get a size mismatch during the expansion. However I dont remember the rules exactly here.

Comment: I think the rule to apply here is "All of the parameter packs expanded by a pack expansion shall have the same number of arguments specified."

Answer (score 0):

I've extracted another code snippet that works, although still doesn't satisfies your needs, but may lead you to something:

```
void f1(int)
{

}

int f1(char)
{
    return 0;
}

template <class Out, class In>
struct UniFunction
{
    typedef Out fn(In);
    typedef fn* ptr;
};

template<class... T>
struct Y
{
  //template<class... U>
  //static void f(T(*...p)(U)...);
    template <class... U>
    struct YY
    {
        static void f(typename UniFunction<T, U>::ptr...)
        {

        }
    };


};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    Y<int>::YY<char>::f(f1);

    return 0;
}
```

This `UniFunction` is just for clarity and maybe show that the double parallel expansion of parameter pack isn't impossible, there's just a small problem.

I think you can still enforce argument type deduction if you provide additionally a "template function" (structure template with typedefs) that will extract (using `type_traits` or something) the argument type and return type from the function pointer. By having that, you should be able to provide the `Y::f` function with just one template parameter (kinda `X...`), extract the argument type from that `X` being a function pointer, then pass it explicitly to `YY` template, as shown here.

Comment: BTW. This can be additionally helpful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Answer (score 0):

MSVC handles your example just fine. On this rare occasion I'm going to say MSVC is right and Clang and GCC are wrong. Clang and GCC do not give an error message that is helpful in any way in suggesting that there is an actual rule in the standard that is being broken here.

Now, when the compiler processes an expression such as `Y<int, void>::f(f1, f1)`, the first thing it has to do is instantiate `Y<int, void>` and perform substitution into the declarations of `Y`'s members. The standard doesn't really say what happens when a template parameter pack from an enclosing template gets substituted into a declaration that still has an unbound template parameter pack that is part of the same pack expansion. In other words, what does the declaration of `f` become after `Y`'s pack `T...` is specified as `{int, void}`?

```
template<class... U>
static void f(T(*...p)(U));
// ^ how can you substitute T... = {int, void} into this?
```

But I think the only reasonable interpretation is that `T` can't get replaced with anything until `U` is also known. So the compiler will have to make a note that `f`'s declaration already contains "bound" values:

```
// this is Y<int, void>'s f
template<class... U>
static void f(T(*...p)(U)) [where T... = {int, void}];
```

(This is not real syntax, obviously).

`U` is not in a non-deduced context, so it should be deduced according to the usual rules, and if it then ends up having a different length from `T`, deduction fails ([temp.deduct.general]/11.1). If deduction succeeds, only then the pack gets expanded since `T` and `U` are both known.

Perhaps the standard needs to be amended to clarify this. But again I think this is the only reasonable interpretation. If it had been meant for `U` to be considered to be in a non-deduced context here, that would need to be explicitly stated in the list of non-deduced contexts in the standard (and it is not).

The alternative would be that the compiler generates something like this during the instantiation of `Y<int, void>`:

```
template<class... U>
static void f(int (*p)(U@[0]), void (*p)(U@[1]));
```

where `U@[i]` is made-up syntax for indexing into the pack `U`, and is a non-deduced context. It would be a real stretch to think that this is what the standard actually means to say.